# Kill the notification area so I can use the awn-notification-area?

Tags: unity, 11.04, notification-area

This is what I get when I try to start an `awn-notification-area` applet in Unity:

> There is already another notification
>   area running on this screen! Please
>   remove the existing notification area
>   and then restart the applet.

So which process should be killed?

Comment: Sorry, I somehow missed Natty mentions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notification area (*PanelTray*) is part of the panel, so I'm afraid this currently won't work in Natty.

Comment: Thats what i thought. Thanks for confirming it though.

Comment: @user13642, if you're going to use AWN, then go with classic desktop and disable Unity plugin in `ccsm`.